# Issue with authenticating Google Earth Engine in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine

I have a conda environment on my local computer through which I have installed the earthengine-api. If I type `python` to run python inline, and then do `import ee` followed by `ee.Authenticate()`, I am able to authenticate earth engine no problem using gCloud. However, when I go to jupyter notebook in that same environment and try to run the same code (`import ee` followed by `ee.Authenticate()` ), I get directed to a slightly different looking authentication page (titled 'notebook authenticator', which has a button that says 'generate token'.

However, when I click that button, I get an error that says "*Project has an incompatible OAuth2 Client configuration. Please select a different project. See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/auth#troubleshooting for details.*"

Any thought of what could be going on?